# Isolating unit-tests with JUnit 5 / Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, testing, junit5

I have a problem with isolating my Unit tests from each other in Kotlin Spring Boot Application (mean functions with @Test annotation). Frameworks/libs I use:

build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.3"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.31"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.5.31"
    id("org.jmailen.kotlinter") version "3.2.0"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_15

repositories {
    maven { url = uri("custom_repository_url") }
}

val springDocVersion = "1.3.9"
val testcontainersVersion = "1.16.0"
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-test")
    implementation("com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.10.3")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.65")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude(group = "org.springframework.boot", module = "spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    }
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.0.0")
    implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.0.0")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")


    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:$springDocVersion")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:$springDocVersion")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-data-rest:$springDocVersion")

    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.7.9")
    implementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-core")


    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
        exclude(module = "mockito-core")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers:$testcontainersVersion")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql:$testcontainersVersion")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:rabbitmq:$testcontainersVersion")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.9.3")
    testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:3.0.1")

    implementation("net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-spring:2.1.0")
    implementation("net.javacrumbs.shedlock:shedlock-provider-jdbc-template:2.1.0")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "15"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperties = mapOf(
        "spring.profiles.active" to "test"
    )
}

tasks.test {
    jvmArgs("--add-opens", "java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED")
}
```

**The problem itself**:

let's consider I have a service class and its test class:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class SomeService(
    private val utilService: UtilService
    private val rabbitTemplate: RabbitTemplate
) {
    // methods (unimportant in this case)
}
```

```
@TestMethodOrder(
    MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation::class
)
class SomeServiceTest {
    private val utilService: UtilService = mockk()
    private val rabbitTemplate: RabbitTemplate = mockk()
    private val subject = SomeService(
        utilService = utilService,
        rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate
    )

    @Order(1)
    @Test
    fun `first test`() {
        // when
        every { utilService.returnString() } returns "firstString"

        // then
        verify(exactly = 1) { rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend() } 
        // other assertions
    }
    
    @Order(2)
    @Test
    fun `second test`() {
        // when
        every { utilService.returnString() } returns "secondString"

        // then
        verify(exactly = 1) { rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend() } 
        // other assertions
    }
}
```

When started separately tests always pass. However, when I run command `gradlew clean build` or just start the test class with all tests together they fail.

For example, an assertion could fail and say that `utilService.returnString()` in the second test returns "firstString" instead of returning "secondString". Or the verify function fails because the function `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend()` was called 2 times instead of 1 (I am completely sure that it could be invoked only 1 time per function running).

So, it seems like some mocks are not isolated from test to test.

I tried to order tests by adding @Order annotation. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.
Also, I added @Isolated annotation to the test class, thinking that some other classes could influence it. However it didn't work.

Comment: I don't see how we'll be able to help if you don't show the `// mocked dependencies` part. Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: @daniu My apologies, I added more information.